# Shooting the Opposite Way? - AndEngine classic tutorial

Tags: android, andengine

Ok, this should be simple enough, but I'm tripping myself up on the math.  Using AndEngine BTW>

I'm using some of the tutorials out there... hero on the left of the screen (landscape) shooting right.  Everything works wonderfully.  Now I'd like to have the hero on the right side of the screen shooting left.  I'm going in circles and would great appreciate some help.  Here is the code I'm using for left hero, shooting right.

```
/** shoots a projectile from the player's position along the touched area */
private void shootProjectile(final float pX, final float pY) {

    int offX = (int) (pX - (hero.getX()));
    int offY = (int) (pY - (hero.getY() + hero.getHeight()/2));
    if (offX <= 0) return;

    // position the projectile on the player and set up path
    projectile = pPool.obtainPoolItem();

    int realX = (int) (mCamera.getWidth() - (hero.getX()  ) );
    float ratio = (float) realX / (float) offX;
    int realY = (int) ((offY * ratio));

    float length = (float) Math.sqrt((realX * realX) + (realY * realY));
    float velocity = 280.0f / .5f; // 480 pixels per (sec)f on screen
    float realMoveDuration = length / velocity;

    // defining a moveBymodifier from the projectile's position to the
    // calculated one

    //this code angles the projectile sprite
    double PI = 3.14159265;
    float  dx = pX -  hero.getX();
    float  dy = pY -  hero.getY()-50;

    double  Radius = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    double Angle = Radius * 180 / PI;

    projectile.setRotation((float)Angle); // sets the angle of the projectile

    //Move modifier for projectile
    MoveByModifier movMByod = new MoveByModifier(realMoveDuration, realX, realY);

    final ParallelEntityModifier par = new ParallelEntityModifier(movMByod);

    DelayModifier dMod = new DelayModifier(0.001f);
    dMod.addModifierListener(new IModifierListener<IEntity>() {

        @Override
        public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> arg0, IEntity arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> arg0, IEntity arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            shootingSound.play();
            projectile.setVisible(true);
            projectile.setPosition(hero.getX(), hero.getY() + hero.getHeight() / 2);
            projectilesToBeAdded.add(projectile);
            projectile.animate(50);

        }
    });

    SequenceEntityModifier seq = new SequenceEntityModifier(dMod, par);
    projectile.registerEntityModifier(seq);
    projectile.setVisible(false);
    mMainScene.attachChild(projectile, 1);
```

I've got the hero positioned fine on the right side.  What do I need to do to get the projectile to move to the left correctly?

Thanks a ton for any help.

MWM

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use DelayModifier the way you do. Instead create a PhysicsHandler for your sprites and then set velocity to the PhysicsHandler. Something like:

```
PhysicsHandler phys = new PhysicsHandler();
projectile.registerUpdateHandler(phys);
phys.setVelocityX(50);
```

and this will take care of moving your projectile. You can also set acceleration on the physics handler the same way. So if you set the initial velocity to point up and left and then set the acceleration pointing down, the projectile will first fly left and up and then gradually fall down. And you don't have to do any calculations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks like the one from http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/
if it is, try this:

```
private void shootProjectile(final float pX, final float pY) {
    int side = 1;
    int offX = (int) (pX - (hero.getX()));
    int offY = (int) (pY - (hero.getY() + hero.getHeight()/2));
    if (offX <= 0){
       side=-1
    }

    // position the projectile on the player and set up path
    projectile = pPool.obtainPoolItem();

    int realX = (int) (mCamera.getWidth() - (hero.getX()  ) ) * side;
    ....
```

I got the same problem with the code from link, with this change i could shoot fot both sides with a player in the middle of screen.